# python if loop stopping after 2 loops and not getting to third

Tags: python, excel, if-statement

I have looked at the other questions and do not see a solution.I need the script to just go through all the files in the folder and put the data in the appropriate tables.

```
for fi in os.listdir('C_data'):
    file_nm = fi
    #fi=[]
    grp= (fi[:3])
    if fi=="A_Pro_Template.xlsx":
        print 'Beginning file:', file_nm
        wb = open_workbook('C_data'+'\\'+file_nm)
        sh = wb.sheet_by_name('Pro')
        grp2=(grp.lower())
        values = []
        for r in range(1,sh.nrows):
        #if len(str(sh.cell(r,7).value))>0:
            v=[None]*9
            v[0]=str(sh.cell(r,0).value)[:6] 
            v[1]=sh.cell(r,2).value   
            v[2]=sh.cell(r,1).value[:10] 
            v[3]=sh.cell(r,3).value[:10] 
            v[4]=sh.cell(r,4).value[:30]        
            v[7]=time
            v[8]=file_nm
            values.append(tuple(v))
            for i in lst_split(len(values)):
                cnxn.cursor().executemany('insert into PROD."'+grp2+'ProX" values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)', values[min(i):max(i)+1])
    if fi=="B_Pro_Template.xlsx":
        print 'Beginning file:', file_nm
        wb = open_workbook('C_data'+'\\'+file_nm)
        sh = wb.sheet_by_name('Pro')# this works until I add instruction tab and then it loops 3 times
        grp2=(grp.lower())
        values = []
        for r in range(1,sh.nrows):
        #if len(str(sh.cell(r,7).value))>0:
            v=[None]*14
            v[0]= None
            v[1]=str(sh.cell(r,0).value)[:6] 
            v[2]=sh.cell(r,2).value   
            v[3]=sh.cell(r,1).value[:10] 
            v[4]=None
            v[5]=sh.cell(r,3).value[:10] 
            v[11]= None
            v[12]=time
           values.append(tuple(v))
            for i in lst_split(len(values)):
                cnxn.cursor().executemany('insert into PROD."'+grp2+'ProX" 
               values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)', 
                values[min(i):max(i)+1])
    if fi=="C_Pro_Template.xlsx":
        print 'Beginning file:', file_nm
        wb = open_workbook('C_data'+'\\'+file_nm)
        sh = wb.sheet_by_name('Pro')
        grp2=(grp.lower())
        values = []
        for r in range(1,sh.nrows):
        #if len(str(sh.cell(r,7).value))>0:
            v=[None]*14
            v[0]= None
            v[1]=str(sh.cell(r,0).value)[:6] 
            v[2]=sh.cell(r,2).value  
            v[3]=sh.cell(r,1).value[:10] 
            v[4]=None
            v[9]=None
            v[11]= None
            v[12]=time
            v[13]=file_nm
            values.append(tuple(v))
            for i in lst_split(len(values)):
                cnxn.cursor().executemany('insert into PROD."'+grp2+'ProX" 
              values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)', 
              values[min(i):max(i)+1])
```

The goal is to have the script run through all the files in the folder but the script is not reaching past the 2nd file.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you're using two types of files with different data. **`glob` allows you to read multiple files and store them as a list** (You can also specify if the text in the file matches a certain string while reading).

You can then **define two functions to read either file types and call them from the list of read files**.

***Here's a hint to how you can implement your code:***

```
def processxxfiles(file):
     #<code to process data in "A_Pro_Template.xlsx" files>

def processAfiles(file):
     #<code to process data in "A_Pro_Template.xlsx" files>

import glob
directory = 'C_data'
xxfiles = sorted (glob.glob(directory + '/*xx_Pro_Template.xlsx')) # This will read all xlsx files with 'xx_Pro_Template' in the filename in the directory and save them to xxfiles list
Afiles = sorted (glob.glob(directory + '/*A_Pro_Template.xlsx'))

# Then use a for loop to iterate over the list of each file type
for file in xxfiles:
    processxxfiles(file)
for file in Afiles:
    processAfiles(file)
```

Comment: 'def processAAAfiles(file):


    def processBBBfiles(file):

        def processCCCfiles(file):

            import glob

Comment: You can define as many functions as you like for each type of file. Then call that function for each file from the filelist.

Did it work for you?

Comment: I receive this error: AAAfiles = sorted (glob.glob(directory + '/*AAA_Pro_Template.xlsx'))
NameError: name 'glob' is not defined

Comment: Did you forget to 'import glob' ?

Comment: 'import datetime
import os
import xlrd
from xlrd import open_workbook

def processADGfiles(file):


  #  def processCLGfiles(file):

   #     def processCSGfiles(file):

    import glob '                                                                                                     Do I not have Glob installed? Thanks

Comment: Possibly, have you checked it in the packages?

run 'help ("glob")' in the python console, it will display help information if installed.

Comment: 'import glob 
import snowflake.connector
from xlrd import open_workbook




  #  def processAAAfiles(file):

   

#time = datetime.datetime.now()



   directory = 'C_data'
   AAAfiles = sorted (glob.glob(directory + '/*AAA_Pro_Template.xlsx'))
 

   for file in AAAiles:
       processAAAfiles'
This runs but I have no idea what it does

Comment: Are you able to post a snapshot of the error message?

Comment: The script runs now but all that happens is                                                                                   for file in AAAfiles:                                                                             
                 processAAAfiles                                                                                 which I have not given it anything to do.

Comment: Are you sure you're calling the right function while processing the files? Or maybe you have copy-pasted the functions but missed modifying it a little in the other ones? 

You can also check by inserting random print statements to identify where the script is failing.